# PHP - Copying array changes internal pointer?

Tags: php, arrays

Have a weird one:

This code outputs "345":

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach ($a as $key => $input)
{
    $ab  = next($a);
    echo $ab;
}
```

But this code outputs "2345":

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$abc = $a;
foreach ($a as $key => $input)
{
    $ab  = next($a);
    echo $ab;
}
```

The only difference between the two codes, is that in the 2nd example the array $a was duplicated into array $abc (line 2)

Does that affect the internal pointer of the array, and how?

**What is the the expected behavior?**

Comment: for me its showing same `2345`

Comment: @Omi I see his behavior

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in PHP 7.

Comment: @Barmar that's why it showing same for me my php version is 7

Comment: if you do `$abc = $a;` after foreach it ll return `345`

Comment: If my answer provided a solution please mark it as correct to close the question

Answer (score 0):

It is all dependent on which PHP version you are running:

Anything lower than 7 will output `345`

while version 7 will output `2345`

You can test [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b341cf9674aba536bdf7a5838d47379fe8b5f01)

Comment: So the expected behavior is to output "2345"?

Comment: BTW - the issue started with 5.2.16.